# Invalid token webview

Tags: android, caching, webview, token

I am getting sometimes an Invalid Token error on my webview since today (It worked well about one month since I started creating my app). It asks me for logging in even when I´m already logged and when I try to log in the error appears. What might be causing this error? 
I thought It could be some problem with cache, so I deleted the cache webview settings. Now I only use this line for cache and the error still happens (at least one time) :

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

I use LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK beacause in one point of the web when you go back you get "document expired" even in the browser, and I avoid this in my webview with that line

I also have a ConnectionBroadReceiver

```
public class ConnectionBroadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        MyFragment.webView.reload();
    } else {

    }

  }
}
```

Last time it happend when I was testing this feature.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. Change this:

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

to:

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```